# Javascript closures withJa assignment operator

Tags: javascript

The value of result is 122, even if the multiplier isn't specified, does it take the value of input automatically? I thought the multiplier operator is the same as x=x*y so x needs to be specified in the first place.

```
function mystery(input) {
  var secret = 4;
  input += 2;
  function mystery2(multiplier) {
    multiplier *= input;
    return secret * multiplier;
  }
  return mystery2;
}

function mystery3(param) {
  function mystery4(bonus) {
    return param(6) + bonus;
  }
  return mystery4;
}

var hidden = mystery(3);
var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
var result = jumble(2);
```

Comment: input is 3, multiplier is 6 ( param=hidden, hidden = mystery2, therefore param(6)...)

Comment: What do you mean by "even if the multiplier isn't specified"? It *is* defined as `6` in `param(6)`.

Comment: Ahh, so param(6)=hidden(3)(6) so multiplier is 6, I'm still trying to grasp the concept of closures :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function mystery(input) {
  var secret = 4;
  input += 2;
  function mystery2(multiplier) {
     multiplier *= input;
     return secret * multiplier;
  }
  return mystery2;
}

function mystery3(param) {
   function mystery4(bonus) {
      return param(6) + bonus;
   }
  return mystery4;
}

var hidden = mystery(3);
  //input=3 +=2 = 5
  //hidden=mystery2

var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
 //param=hidden
 //jumble=mystery4

var result = jumble(2);
  //bonus=2
 //result=jumble(2)=mystery4(2)
 //result=param(6)+bonus
 //result=mystery2(6)+2
 //multiplier=6
 //result=input*multiplier*secret+2
 //result=5*6*4+2
 //result=?
```

You could easify your code:

```
mystery=input=>multiplier=>(input+2)*multiplier*4;
mystery3=param=>bonus=>param(6)+bonus;
result=mystery3(mystery(3))(2);
```